# Angular service is not initializing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

I have a service checking user authentication to redirect to login or logged in area.

## services.js:

```
var servicesModule = angular.module('servicesModule', []);

servicesModule.service('loginService', ['$state', function($state){

    console.log('Inside');

    var ref = new Firebase("https://feedback-system.firebaseio.com/");
    var authData = ref.getAuth();

    console.log('Inside');

    if (authData) {


      $state.go('tabs.courses');
      console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);

    } else {

      $state.go('login');
    }

}]);
```

## Controller:

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('feedback-system', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'servicesModule', 'coursesModule', 'feedbackModule', 'loginModule', 'tabsModule']);

ionicApp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

ionicApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })

  .state('tabs', {
    url: '/tabs',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'tabsCtrl'
  })

  .state('tabs.courses', {
    url: '/courses',
    views:{
      'coursesView':{    
        templateUrl: 'views/courses.html',
        controller: 'coursesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabs.feedback', {
    url: '/feedback',
    views:{
      'feedbackView':{
        templateUrl: 'views/feedback.html',
        controller: 'feedbackCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabs.notifications', {
    url: '/notifications',
    views:{
      'notificationsView':{
        templateUrl: 'views/notification.html',
        controller: 'notificationCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/courses");
});
```

## index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="feedback-system">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngcordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- Firebase -->

    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angularfire.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->

    <script src="js/services/services.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->

    <script src="js/controllers/loginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/coursesCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/feedbackCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/tabsCtrl.js"></script>

    <!-- Application -->

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I am injecting it in app.js main module and index.html, there is no error at all, but nothing is happening, no logging nothing in console.
Any idea why this servies.js is not executed?

## Update:

Sorry i forgot to mention that this service worked exactly how it is now without any return before, it simply stopped working today.

Answer (score 1):

I think your service declaration is went wrong. wrap the content inside the service in a return function block.

```
servicesModule.service('loginService', ['$state', function($state){

    return function() {
        console.log('Inside');

        var ref = new Firebase("https://feedback-system.firebaseio.com/");
        var authData = ref.getAuth();

        console.log('Inside');

        if (authData) {


          $state.go('tabs.courses');
          console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);

        } else {

          $state.go('login');
        }
    }

}]);
```

in controller

```
servicesModule.controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'loginService', function($scope, loginService){

       loginService();

}]);
```

Comment: u dont return a function in service, factory is used for that i think, correct me if im wrong

Comment: @Faizan, a factory returns whatever you want (an array, a function, a plain object, a string). A service returns a `new`'ed function. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
var servicesModule = angular.module('servicesModule', []);

servicesModule.service('loginService', ['$state', '$firebaseAuth', '$firebase',  function($state,$firebaseAuth ,$firebase ){

return function() {
    console.log('Inside');

    var ref = new Firebase("https://feedback-system.firebaseio.com/");
    var authData = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    console.log('Inside');

    if (authData) {


      $state.go('tabs.courses');
      console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);

    } else {

      $state.go('login');
    }
}
}]);
```

Inject `$firebaseAuth` and `$firebase` and try. Also can you show the controller and how you are injecting this service in index.html?

Comment: i didnt add controller since its bit long and didnt think it wud be necessary to c that since a service shud simply execute atleast once when the app runs, i will try the solution u suggested but my point was even the first line console.log is not run so it means service is simply not seen.

Comment: Sure do try injecting `$firebaseAuth` and `$firebase` as mentioned above.Oh I didn't realize one fundamental thing, you got to return something from a service, that's the purpose and the design in general! I shall modify my answer

Comment: the purpose of service is to execute something before u go to your view and one of the uses of that is to get some data ready for controller to use. I have successfully run this service before exactly how it is now, it simply stopped executing today.

Comment: that sounds strange! that's amusing

Comment: ok i did try adding $firebaseAuth and $firebase, no difference as expected, $firebase is supposed to be added only in the main app module.

Comment: check this out, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/403 

As one of the answers suggest, "move the state transition back into the controller and use a deferred within your service method".

Comment: Wonder why that would be a minus..!! np!!

Comment: im sorry i didnt do this minus thing, thats y i wondered wen u mentioned it n saw it after reading ur message, let me try to fix it.

I will try your suggested solution now, thanks

Comment: I downvoted because `['$state', $firebaseAuth, $firebase,  function($state,$firebaseAuth ,$firebase )` isn't correct. It should be `['$state', '$firebaseAuth', '$firebase',  function($state,$firebaseAuth ,$firebase )`

Comment: @JoshBeam thats fair! it was a typo while I was editing. No worries! I shall edit it back! Faizan, sure try it out!

Comment: @JoshBeam thanks.. Sorry it was a typo.. it's too late in the night in India :D thanks.. cheers!

Comment: i tried, but nothing will work since my problem is not with state.go because it worked before, my problem is the services.js is not seen, i put alerts and logs and tried making another factory server but nothing is seen.

Comment: please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109095/i-have-ngcordova-local-notification-working-how-can-i-make-it-trigger-for-every