# I have ngCordova local notification working, how can i make it trigger for every user

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, localnotification, ngcordova

I have an ionicPopup with textarea where when user enters text, saves in firebase. On this change of value im able to trigger ngCordova local notification on mobile who's user has entered data.
How can i make this value change trigger same notification on every logged in user's mobile.

## Service:

```
servicesModule.factory("Profile", ["$firebaseObject",
  function($firebaseObject) {
    return function(new_value) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://feedback-system.firebaseio.com/Courses/" + 'newValue');
      var new_value_ref = ref.child(new_value);
      return $firebaseObject(new_value_ref);
    }
  }
]);
```

## Controller:

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('localNotificationModule', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

ionicApp.controller('localNotificationCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaLocalNotification', '$state', 'Profile', '$firebase', 'Firebase', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification, $state, Profile, $firebase, Firebase){

        $scope.profile = Profile("physicsmarie");

        // calling $save() on the synchronized object syncs all data back to our Firebase database
        $scope.testNotification = function() {
          $scope.profile.$save().then(function() {
            scheduleDelayedNotification($scope.profile.name);
          }).catch(function(error) {
            alert('Error!');
          });
        };

function scheduleDelayedNotification(newValue) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                id: 1,
                title: 'New Notification',
                text: newValue,
                autoCancel: true
            }).then(function (result) {
                alert("Notification Set");
            });
    });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK its working using,

```
firebaseRef.on('value', function(){
    local notification scheduling
});
```

with 2 problems though.

1. Triggering notification on message senders side as well.
2. Notification fails when app's state is 'background'.